# TypeError for re.split in Python

Tags: python, list, split, typeerror

I have a question about using re for Python on re.split.
Firstly, the records list contains 100 data.
When I tried to retrieve a specfic data, it works:

```
content = records[0].get("AB") #I'm getting the article content from pubmed btw
nom = []
nom = re.split(r"\B\s(?=[^\s:]+:)", content) #trying to split into paragraphs
print nom
```

However, if i try to retrieve the full set of data using for in, I'm getting typeerror which expected string or buffer. This is the code:

```
for record in records:
    content = record.get("AB")
    nom = []
    nom = re.split(r"\B\s(?=[^\s:]+:)", content)
    print nom
```

The error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 4, in 
>   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/re.py", line 167, in split
>   return _compile(pattern, 0).split(string, maxsplit)
>   TypeError: expected string or buffer

Anyone can explain to me why is this happening? How can I correct it to retrieve the full set of data?

Comment: if you print content in your loop what do you see?

Comment: Well, the error occurs because record.get("AB") is not a string or buffer.

Comment: This probably isn't related, but `//` isn't the comment signifier in Python. Try `#`.

Comment: `nom = []` is unnecessary.

Comment: Adding `print type(content)` before the line where exception occurs should tell you what you need to know.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham there is results and the error at the end.

Comment: so you don't see `None`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yup. There is result and the error. It's not nothing. I'm just worried if the data I'm retrieving is incorrect since I'm having error.

Comment: so `if content:nom = re.split(r"\B\s(?=[^\s:]+:)", content)` still throws an error?

Comment: it's probably None, so perhaps a type check before splitting?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes. Even though I have gotten the result, I can't add into my mysql.

Comment: Try putting `try: ... except: ...` around the `split` and print the value of `content` as well as `type(content)` in the except clause.

Comment: @tobias_k, printing content before using re.split should show what content is no?

Comment: @tobias_k Found out one of the data type is NoneType. What can I do with it?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Found out one of the data in is NoneType. Is it the cause?

Comment: Yes, NoneType is not a string or buffer. So checking `if content:nom = re.split(r"\B\s(?=[^\s:]+:)", content)` gave you the same error?

Comment: Have a look at your data. Seems there are some entries with not `AB` attribute. Either fix the data, or just ignore those entries. Depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @tobias_k I found out one of the data is causing the error. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I found out one of the data is causing the error. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you know `records[0]` is OK.

Clearly, one of the other 99 lines is causing it to choke. I'm guessing the last one. A quick and dirty solution would be to change your `get` to specify a string default, rather than the default default (!) `None`:

```
content = record.get("AB",'')
```